# Is it possible to find similar names within same column and all similar names be replaced by 1 common name

Tags: vba, excel

I thought of fuzzy lookup to find similar names but it needs two separate columns of data . Is there any other way ?

Comment: Without vba, you can use find/replace with wildcards to find all "matches" and rename them. I suggest trying that with macro recorder to get the code. Use "find all" 1st though. It'll give you a list of cells/ranges found to make sure you don't replace something you need to keep.

Comment: The question is how similar is "similar"? Wildcards might do the trick for you, but if wildcard strings don't reliably match (eg Rebecca, Becky, Bex, etc.) then you'll need to create some kind of synonym map. We could help you with either but could you provide some sample data in your question.

Comment: @Ambie - ABC Limited, Abc Ltd, ABC and ABC L.T.D are all same Also BCD Infrastructure and BCD Infra are same .

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF(Range,"*yourtexttofind*")
```